# Blind effect on image

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a vertical (upwards) blind effect on the children of a container (making them disappear from the container) on click of the container, but for some reason this is only working on text. The icon in the container is not moving at all, I wondered if this is natural or if some of the code might be affecting it this way.

The jquery is `$(this).children().toggle( "blind", {direction: "vertical" }, 1000 );`

The html looks like:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child" id="icon">
     <img />
   </div>
   <div class="child" id="text">
     <h1> Some Title </h1>
     <p> Some text </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The only css on the child is a `float:left` (i didn't build this so don't bash me for the floating layouts) and `display: table`

I didn't think the float could affect this, as the float is a left to right affect, and i am toggling vertical. I chanced the display to block just to see how it would work and was getting the same results. On a similar element I am doing the same effect and it works fine, the difference being the image and the float.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe additional div will help?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>
       <div class="child" id="icon">
       </div>
       <div class="child" id="text">
       <h1> Some Title </h1>
       <p> Some text </p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding another div did nothing at first, but then I changed the target of the jquery to `$this.children().children()` and it works more or less, but unfortunately it is literally toggling the children, making both text and image toggle separately instead of sliding up together. Any idea's on this? I'm thinking of just using some of appearance css for it myself, but if there is something easier or cleaner for it, I'd appreciate the hint. Or if we can get it to actually target that new div the way it originally should of been that'd be awesome.

Comment: Try add css: ".parent > div { display:inline-block; }" or maybe use slideToggle() instead of toggle?

Comment: I've tried both, both work for the main purpose but it goes back to the icon not moving.

Comment: Maybe it will help to add that i just removed `"blind"` from the toggle, and it works, but from right to left, even with `{direction: "vertical"}` or `{direction: "up"}`

Comment: And in last case you use slideToggle() or slideToggle({your parameters}) ? Try use slideToggle() (no parameters) on this additional <div> (add display:inline-block; on this div) under parent class. It's very strange that it does not work. ;)

Comment: got it to work using `$(this).children().animate({marginTop: '-=300px'}, 1000);` thanks!